# 'base.document.layout' object has no attribute 'header' odoo14 - trying to display custom fields in report

Tags: html, odoo, qweb, odoo-14

with a custom module, I have added the two fields header and footer to every res.company object. These are fields of the type binary.

I now want to display them in my document layout in qweb.
Unfortunately, odoo tells me

```
'base.document.layout' object has no attribute 'header'
```

This is what my layout looks like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="web.external_layout_boxed">
        <div t-attf-class="header o_company_#{company.id}_layout" t-att-style="report_header_style">
            <div class="o_boxed_header">
            <div class="row mb8">
                <div class="col-6">
<!--HERE-->         <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="image_data_uri(company.header)" alt="brief_header"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 text-right mb4">
                    <h4 class="mt0" t-field="company.report_header"/>
                    <div name="company_address" class="float-right mb4">
                        <span class="company_address" t-field="company.partner_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: true}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div t-attf-class="article o_report_layout_boxed o_company_#{company.id}_layout" t-att-data-oe-model="o and o._name" t-att-data-oe-id="o and o.id" t-att-data-oe-lang="o and o.env.context.get('lang')">
            <div class="pt-5">
                <t t-call="web.address_layout"/>
            </div>
            <t t-raw="0"/>
        </div>

        <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="image_data_uri(company.footer)" alt="brief_footer"/>
    </t>
```

as you can see I am trying to access the header with company.header

the pictures appended show you that the fields exist on the type.

[image: you can see that the fields exist on the model res.company]

[image: fields list for res.company]

What am I doing wrong? How can I correctly display the uploaded images in the external_layout_boxed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering the document, the [company](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/models/base_document_layout.py#L102) variable is set to `wizard` object not to the user company. Odoo will try to access `header` and `footer` in `base.document.layout` model.

To fix that issue, alter the document layout model like following:

```py
class BaseDocumentLayout(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'base.document.layout'
    
    header = fields.Binary(related="company_id.header")
    footer = fields.Binary(related="company_id.footer")
```

You can find an example in [l10n_de](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/l10n_de/report/din5008_report.xml#L60) module where they created a new report layout and altered [base.document.layout](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/l10n_de/models/base_document_layout.py#L5) to use new fields like `street`, `city` or `bank_ids`

Comment: it almost works for me except I get the following error: TypeError: Model 'base.document.layout' does not exist in registry.
I have added 'depends': ['base'] in my manifest file

Comment: The `base.document.layout` model is defined in `web` module

Comment: To anyone wondering, you have to add 'depends': ['web'] to your __manifest__.py file!